# Removing Camera Controls from UIImagePicker - How to Scale Up to Full Screen - iPhone / iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have the below code in my app which displays a UIImagePicker minus the camera controls.

```
#define CAMERA_SCALAR 1.32 

@implementation CameraViewController

- (id)init {
// Remove standard controls from UIImagePicker and make full screen
if (self = [super init]) {
    self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.toolbarHidden = YES;
    self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    self.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.cameraViewTransform, 1, CAMERA_SCALAR);          
}
return self;
}
```

Initially when I removed set showsCameraControls to NO I got a black bar on the screen where the controls had been. To offset this I added in the self.cameraViewTransform line to scale up the view.

This works, however it distorts the image. I think what I need to do is also scale the height by the same ratio as the width.

Can anyone advise me on the best way to do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting your question, but to scale the width as well, you can

```
self.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_SCALAR, CAMERA_SCALAR);
```

instead of

```
self.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.cameraViewTransform, 1, CAMERA_SCALAR);
```

But of course, this will push the sides of the camera view out of screen.

In principle, I think there is no best choice in this case (showing exactly what the camera shows in fullscreen), because the origin of the problem is the difference of the aspect ratio of the screen/camera. You either have to miss part of the view, or distort the view, is my thinking.

Comment: Thanks Barley - that's what I thought. Is 1.32 the best scalar value to use or is there a tighter one ?

Comment: In a book I read (Pro iOS5 Augmented Reality by Kyle Roche), it used 1.3.

Comment: Thanks - wonder what the maths is behind this - is theory shouldn't the scalar be 56 / 480 ? (56 being the width of the contols). Wierd.

Comment: That is actually what I am wondering too. At first, I was convinced that it would be the ratio between HD(1.777) and VGA(1.333). `1.777/1.333 = 1.333`. But later I realized that iPhone screen is not even VGA aspect ratio (480/320 = 1.5). I feel I am close to the fact, but there should be something that is going under the hood which I am missing.